How obtain the device path for all files on each disk device?
I have retrieved the disk devices using IoGetDeviceInterfaces() and then parsed the string to obtain the DeviceObject for the disk device. What should I do next to traverse all the files on this disk and print out their "device paths"?
I am referring to paths in the format starting with "\Device\Harddisk0Volume4...".
My code is:
#define _NTIFS_INCLUDED_

#include<initguid.h>
#include<ntddk.h>
#include<ntdef.h>
#include<ntstrsafe.h>
#include<ntifs.h>
#include<ntddstor.h>

VOID DriverUnload(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject);

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath) {

    NTSTATUS status;

    DriverObject->DriverUnload = DriverUnload;

    PZZWSTR paths = NULL;
    WCHAR wctmp[2048];

    //Get all disk
    status = IoGetDeviceInterfaces(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK,
        NULL, 0, &paths);

    if (status==STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        
        ULONG index = 0;
        ULONG ltemp1;

        UNICODE_STRING str1;
        PFILE_OBJECT fileObject;
        PDEVICE_OBJECT deviceObject;

        str1.MaximumLength = sizeof(wctmp);
        str1.Buffer = wctmp;


        while (paths[index] != 0) {

            ltemp1 = wcslen(paths + index);
            str1.Length = ltemp1*sizeof(WCHAR);
            RtlCopyMemory(wctmp, paths + index, str1.Length);

            status = IoGetDeviceObjectPointer(&str1, GENERIC_READ, &fileObject, &deviceObject);

            if (NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
                if (deviceObject) {
                    // ===TODO====

                }
            }
            index += ltemp1 + 1;
        }
        ExFreePool(paths);
    }

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

VOID DriverUnload(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject) {
    KdPrint(("Bye!"));
}

I don't know how to try yet, I hope the problem can be solved.

"What should I do next to traverse all the files on this disk and print out their "device paths"?" - I don't think Windows exposes the filesystem structure this way, because you're operating at a level below the filesysterm: the raw bytes or blocks (or maybe even cylinders?) of the device. (But I'm probably wrong, but look forward to being corrected!)

However, one fact is that when I use PsLocateProcessImageName() to retrieve the file path corresponding to a process, it returns a path starting with '\Device\Harddisk0Volume4' instead of one starting with '??'. To work with this function, I am looking for a function that can retrieve and iterate through the file's DevicePath.
